# How to make .DACPAC from Azure Sql Server using Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

I'm using Terraform to create my environment and I'd like to deploy Azure Sql Server along with other things. I use terraform so I can easily destroy all deployed things and reduce costs when I'm not using them.
So, I decided that I can add Azure Sql Server into my Terraform file but I need to store my information into backup file so I can restore it with "Azure SQL Database deployment" task from pipeline. Hovewer, I haven't find any indication that it is possible to create a .DACPAC from within Azure DevOps.
So, is there a way to create and save a backup of my database (preferrably, into a blob storage) from Azure DevOps pipeline? I looked into azure shell (az sql database), but haven't find anything of value

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after researching some more time, I've found this gem https://markheath.net/post/backup-restore-sql-database-azure-cli. In this article author uses `az sql db export` and `az sql db import` to save database into BACPAC and restore it back on the clean database. But here comes a pitfall - Azure CLI task v1.0 uses **CMD** so it's not easy to translate from **Bash** syntax to **CMD**, and Azure CLI task v2.0 *preview* which has option to choose **Bash** as an interpreter doesn't have az installed (it's probably a bug and already has a post on uservoice) so one needs to rewrite the script into **Powershell** if they want to use it.
So, it's not completely what I was looking for but it does its job.